# React change navigate active link while allowing the user to click to move to other nav link

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i'm trying to implement a feature where people can click on a nav item to move to a section and when they are traveling in the page the active nav link will set itself to active when they arrive to a new section

I managed to do the first part and people can jump to sections with the navbar

```
function Nav({ activeTab, onNav, aboutRef, homeRef }) {
  // Example of using useReducer
  const [yOffSet] = useScroll();
  const [isSticky, setIsSticky] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (yOffSet > 400) setIsSticky(true);
    if (yOffSet < 400) setIsSticky(false);
    if (yOffSet < 600) onNav(homeRef, `Home`);
    if (yOffSet > 600) onNav(aboutRef, `About`);
  }, [yOffSet, setIsSticky, aboutRef, homeRef, onNav]);

  return (
    <div ref={homeRef} className={`${styles.nav} container`}>
      <Logo />
      <div className={`${isSticky ? styles.sticky : ``} ${styles.links}`}>
        {navLinks.map((link) => (
          <NavLink
            onClick={() => onNav(link === `Home` ? homeRef : aboutRef, link)}
            isActive={activeTab === link}
            linkName={link}
            key={link}
          />
        ))}
        <SocialLink className="margin-left-medium" name="Linkedin" />
        <SocialLink name="GitHub" />
      </div>
      <PrimaryButton message={`Get in touch`} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

App Function

```
function App() {
  const homeRef = useRef(null);
  const aboutRef = useRef(null);
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(`Home`);

  const scrollToItem = (ref, link) => {
    ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    setActiveTab(link);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Nav
        activeTab={activeTab}
        homeRef={homeRef}
        aboutRef={aboutRef}
        onNav={scrollToItem}
      />
      <Hero />
      <About aboutRef={aboutRef} />
    </>
  );
}
```

my problem is that I have a collusion between the features, when im setting the active tab based on the yOffset I can't move between sections because of the yOffSet

Comment: The logo question, I got the logo in both! See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4l2U.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Save yourself the hassle.

https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll